# How to create a multiple plots having same X axis?

Tags: r, layout, plot

I am trying to make a single plot using dataset with same X axis but different Y axis. As an example, I have this dataset:

```r
A1 <- rnorm(100)
B1 <- rnorm(100)
B2 <- rnorm(100)
B3 <- rnorm(100)

grid <- matrix(c(1:3),nrow=3,ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
layout(grid)

plot(A1,B1)
plot(A1,B2)
plot(A1,B3)
```

This is what I get and comes with multiple X axis:

[image]

I know how to do it using `ggplot2` but I am looking for another way like using `layout`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the solution you provide work if you just make sure that you specify the limits on the x-axis for each plot and don't plot the x-axis in the upper two plots?

Comment: Alternative would be to use `xyplot()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Both works pretty well! however, I found another solution working with par(mar) and layout function. The top and bottom number in par(mar) needs to be set as zero for any middle plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its too easy by working with par(mar) and layout function.

```
par(mar=c(6,6,4,4))
layout(matrix(1:3, ncol = 1), widths = 1, heights = c(2.3,2,2.3), respect = FALSE)
par(mar = c(0, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(B1,A1,xaxt='n')
par(mar = c(0, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
plot(B2,A1,xaxt='n')
par(mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
plot(B3,A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can

1. Use the `mfcol` argument in `par` to set the number of plots, use `mar` to leave out the margins, `oma` to add space to axis which you will make with `axis`, and `mgp` to set the space for the axis label you will make.
2. Make the plots without axis with `axes = FALSE`.
3. Use `box` to add the boxes around the plots.
4. Add the axis labels in the end with `mtext`.

Here is an example

```
set.seed(32273438)
A1 <- rnorm(100)
B1 <- rnorm(100)
B2 <- rnorm(100)
B3 <- rnorm(100)

par(mfcol = c(3, 1), mar = numeric(4), oma = c(4, 4, .5, .5), 
    mgp = c(2, .6, 0))
plot(A1, B1, axes = FALSE)
axis(2L)
box()
plot(A1, B2, axes = FALSE)
axis(2L)
box()
plot(A1, B3, axes = FALSE)
axis(1L)
axis(2L)
box()
mtext("A1", side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 2.2)
mtext("B", side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 2.2)
```

[image]

You may have issues with overlapping y-ticks but you solve this with a the `yaxp` argument of `par`.

Comment: This is a great solution. Just one question. Assuming each of those stacked plots had a different Y label. How would you handle that with mtext?

Comment: You can do something like `mtext("p1", side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 2.2, adj = 5/6)`,
 `mtext("p2", side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 2.2, adj = 3/6)`, and `mtext("p3", side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 2.2, adj = 1/6)`. Though, you will need to adjust the `adj`s to get something that look more neat (i.e. is centered).

Comment: Thanks! I tried using `at=c(0.1,0.4,0.6,0.85)` and seems to work but with a lot of trial and error. Is there no way to index things with the reference of where the plots split? i.e. to use a coordinate system of each individual plot?

Comment: Would it also work to set just the x axis as false in the original plot statements instead of the `axes = FALSE`?